# WordPress Advanced Custom Fields Getting field data from different post

Tags: php, wordpress

So I am having an issue with the following code:

```
            <?php 

            $posts = get_field('story_character');

            if( $posts ): ?>
                <?php foreach( $posts as $post): // variable must be called $post (IMPORTANT) ?>
                    <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>
                    By <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                    <span><?php the_field('story_character'); ?></span>
                  <?php endforeach;wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php 

            $posts = get_field('story_character');

            if( $posts ): ?>
                <?php foreach( $posts as $post): // variable must be called $post (IMPORTANT) ?>
                    <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>
                    of <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_field('char_tribe'); ?></a>
                    <span><?php the_field('story_character'); ?></span>
                  <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

Everything after the first query does not show up and I cannot figure out why...What am I missing?

Comment: what's return the `get_field('story_character')` ?

Comment: To answer the question in the title, use:
`get_field( 'name', id );`
ex: `get_field( 'story_character', 23 );`

Comment: I don't think I can use an id...it's meant to be dynamic as it's a list of posts.